# merge function in Rarmadillo

Tags: r, rcpp

How can I implement a simple merge function to merge two matrices each having two columns with a common column `x` using Rarmadillo? In other words, I want a function `my_merge_cpp(mat1, mat2)` which will give the same result using the following R code:

```
mat1 = as.matrix(data.frame(x=1:5, y1=2:6)) ## an example
mat2 = as.matrix(data.frame(x=3:7, y2=3:7)) ## an example
as.matrix(merge(mat1, mat2, all=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use `data.table`.  Try it with larger data, I would be rather surprised to see you beat it with a home-grown Rcpp or RcppArmadillo solution.

Code

```
library(data.table)
mat1 <- data.table(x=1:5, y1=2:6)  ## an example
mat2 <- data.table(x=3:7, y2=3:7)  ## an example
mat1[mat2, on="x", nomatch=NULL]
```

Demo

```
R> library(data.table)
R> mat1 <- data.table(x=1:5, y1=2:6)  ## an example
R> mat2 <- data.table(x=3:7, y2=3:7)  ## an example
R> mat1[mat2, on="x", nomatch=NULL]
   x y1 y2
1: 3  4  3
2: 4  5  4
3: 5  6  5
R>
```

Comment: But indeed I would do many merge steps nested within RcppArmadillo functions. Each of the merge steps simply merges 2-column data frame mat1 and mat2 (or matrix) on the x key

Comment: You may want to review a few aspects of your approach. First, RcppArmadillo is only for _numerical matrices_ so your insistence on using with data.frames will likely result in extra copies.  Second, RcppArmadillo is for Linear Algebra.  Merging data is something different.